# Export Oracle Table Data by DBMS_XMLGEN -> How to Import?

Tags: oracle

I can easy export table data by using DBMS_XMLGEN. But is there a package to reimport this XML?

```
create table foo(
  id number
 ,text varchar2(30)
)
/

insert into foo values (1,'hello');
insert into foo values (2,'world');

declare
  l_foo_xml Clob;
begin
  l_foo_xml := DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select * from foo');
  delete from foo;
  --- ???? insert the xml into foo ???
end;
/
```

Thanks 
Christian

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [DBMS_XMLSAVE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_xmlsav.htm#i1049047)?

The Oracle documentation doesn't give examples of it's use, so a quick google will show you.

Here is something based on your example. (Which was inspired by the information from [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6159))

```
create table foo(
  id number
 ,text varchar2(30)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p(p_xml IN CLOB, 
                              p_table_name IN VARCHAR2) 
IS

  l_context    DBMS_XMLSAVE.CTXTYPE;

  l_rows    NUMBER;

BEGIN

  l_context := DBMS_XMLSAVE.NEWCONTEXT(p_table_name); 

  l_rows := DBMS_XMLSAVE.INSERTXML(l_context,
                                   p_xml); 

  DBMS_XMLSAVE.CLOSECONTEXT(l_context); 

END;
/
```

Call the procedure p with some sample xml

```
DECLARE
  l_xml CLOB;
BEGIN
  l_xml := '<ROWSET>
                <ROW num="1">
                <ID>123</ID>                
                <TEXT>Some Text</TEXT>
                </ROW>
             </ROWSET>';

  p(p_xml => l_xml, 
    p_table_name => 'FOO');
END;
/
```

Query the table

```
select *
from foo
```

[image]